# Maximum number of std::shared_ptr managed objects per process

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Is there a limit in the maximum number of `std::shared_ptr` managed objects per process?

Asking this because there is a [maximum number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3714935/maximum-number-of-mutexes-per-process-thread-in-windows) of mutexes per process.
If the implementation of `std::shared_ptr` is using mutex, isn't there a similar limit in the number of objects managed objects?

An answer discussing mutex-based and atomic-operation-base implementations is more than welcome.

Comment: I doubt there is any limit as per the C++ spec. There may be platform-specific limits. So, what OS/compiler are you using?

Comment: There is no such limit specified in the standard. Any implementation-specific limits are of course specific to the implementation ;-) (and would thus be documented in the specific standard library docs), but I'd expect most implementations to use an atomic counter instead of a mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally no, there is no limit because the shared_ptr implementations on common OS's do not use mutexes under the hood (they use atomic increment/decrement functions).  Also, an implementation could, for example, choose to manage all reference count accesses with a single mutex.  Might be slow in some cases, but it could work.